# Use pseudo classes with variables in Sass

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-class

I've been unable to wrap my head around how to execute this idea I have using pseudo classes with variables in Sass.

**My case**

I'm creating a form which has several `input[type=text]`fields and an `input[type=email]` field and for those fields I want to create the `normal`, `hover` and `focus` states.

So the compiled CSS would look like this:

```
input[type=text],
input[type=email] { background:#eee; }

input[type=text]:hover,
input[type=email]:hover { background:#aaa; }

input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=email]:focus { background:#666; }
```

So I created this variable:

```
$inputs: "input[type=text], input[type=email]";
```

And for the `normal` state I have:

```
#{$inputs} { background:#eee; }
```

So in my naive mind I thought that doing `#{$inputs}:hover { background:#aaa; }` would work... but it doesn't, of course, Sass can't just "guess" what I want just like that :p

Which is why I'm here.

**Question**

Any suggestions on how I can use pseudo classes on variables like I describe above?

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for this:

```
input[type=text],
input[type=email]
{
   background:#eee;

   &:hover
   {
       background:#aaa;
   }

   &:focus
   {
       background:#666;
   }

}
```

Here is demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ApxSB/

As @ricardozea said, you may also put the selectors in a variable like this:

```
$inputs: "input[type=text], input[type=email]";

#{$inputs}
{
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/ApxSB/1/

Comment: Oh man, I just figured it out, yes, I ended up exactly with what you just said, doh! lol. I think I was so distracted by how **[Bourbon's HTML5 Inputs mixin](http://bourbon.io/docs/#html5-input-types)** works that I thought I had to do something similar. Thanks man!

Comment: Ths happen to all of us @ricardozea glad you found a solution

Comment: BTW, I think your solution would be using `#{$inputs}` :). Thanks again!. PS. And Thanks for the fiddle as well.